# Schema-validation: missing table [game]

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I think it may be possible dupplicate of this: [Schema-validation: missing table [hibernate_sequences]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39675714/7947794) but I can't figure it out.

So in my `application.properties` file I have this option: `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` and I receive this error:

`Schema-validation: missing table [game]`

Why I am receiving this?

Here is my `Game` class and `User` class:

Game:

```
@Entity
public class Game {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "GAME_NUMBER")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long gameNumber;

    private int playerScore;
    private int NPCScore;
    private Date datetime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

    public Game() {}

    public Game(int playerScore, int nPCScore, Date datetime) {
        super();
        this.playerScore = playerScore;
        this.NPCScore = nPCScore;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
} + getters & setters
```

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private long userId;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Game> games;

    @ElementCollection
    private List<Date> startSessions;

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, List<Game> games, List<Date> startSessions) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.games = games;
        this.startSessions = startSessions;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`validate` validates that the entities are compatible against the target, to a degree it's not foolproof. Anyway, whatever database you are trying to validate against does not have a table called `game` in which to store the entities.

This answer goes into more detail about what `validate` does.

[Hibernate - hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695861/hibernate-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-validate)

specifically,

> checks the presence of tables, columns, id generators

Without knowing your database/expectations (are you expecting it to be created, or using Flyway/Liquibase to create/update the database etc.) I can't answer if `validate` is correct for your use case.

You could try `create-drop` to create and drop the table on startup/shutdown, but this isn't a solution for any production control over a database.

Comment: I fixed the problem and created the table [game] and now it works fine.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same as I changed to Hibernate 5.4.0.Final.
Either Hibernate suddenly has problems to recognize the default schema or the driver does not return the schema properly.
I was able to bypass it by either adding the schema definition to the table definition.

```
@Table(name = "GAME", schema = "PUBLIC")
```

or by adding a default schema in persistence.xml.

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="PUBLIC" />
```

Comment: Worked for me to set `hibernate.default_schema` as a system property with the appropriate value

Comment: @Bevor - Great, But If I set other than PUBLIC, say BATCH then it gives same error. Any reason why ?

Comment: @Ash_P Don't know, sorry. Does BATCH exist at all?

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget permissions:
GRANT select, insert, update, delete, alter ON table_name TO usr_name;

Comment: solved it for me. Seems like JPA doesn't tell you that you don't have permissions explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

This error can appear while using spring boot with flywayDB.
The issue might be due to the wrong naming convention of script files, which were used by flywayDB.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming

Answer (score 1):

Add this in application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: game
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here in 2023, I resolved the issue by adding the following:
`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = dbName`

This is how my application.properties look like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName
spring.datasource.username=//your username
spring.datasource.password=//your password

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema = dbName

#flyway configuration
spring.flyway.user = //your username
spring.flyway.password = //your password
spring.flyway.defaultSchema = dbName

#SHOW-SQL
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql = true
```

Comment: Nicely done, mate. Exactly my case. I was stuck in this while maintainig many-to-many mapping

Answer (score 0):

The SQL standard requires names stored in uppercase.
If you named the table/fields in lowercase - JPA can automatically convert case to upper and trying to search names in this case, but write to logs in lower `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate version **5.6.9**,
Case-sensitive implementation:

```
hibernate:
        physical_naming_strategy: 'org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i'm using `Flyway` and have set in the propertie file `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate`.

The Error happens because I forgot to name the migration file correctly.

Here instead of `V3__MIGRATION_NAME.sql` I forgot the an underscore and had this : `V3_MIGRATION_NAME.sql`

`V3_MIGRATION_NAME.sql` --> `V3__MIGRATION_NAME.sql`

---^-------------------------------^^

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the logs, the idea does not find the migration file... In short, if you create a db.migration folder as in the video (where the author directly creates one directory, through a dot at once), then if you look at the Idea of the path to the migration file, it will be like a single db.migration directory, while Fly is looking for migration along the db/migration path. If I understand correctly, multiple dot-separated directories are created only when creating PACKAGES, and here we are creating a directory outside the java code/folder. Therefore, I first created a directory, db, and then a migration directory in it. there is no need to add any properties.