# In Spring Boot application I am getting this as error, Any help will be appriciated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am getting this error while running the hibernate application. any help will be appreciated. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479406/schema-validation-missing-table-game Check this..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error message clearly states that `country` table is missing in your database. There can be multiple reasons for this issue. But you can resolve this issue by using any of the following solution:

1. Manually create country table before starting your application OR
2. Add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` property to your `application.properties` file to tell spring boot to create table automatically.

Refer [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)